# Call phone from Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, telephony

I have a requirement to create a web page , which will load all the phone numbers (mobile/landline) of a user from data base.
These numbers will be displayed like radio buttons and another button "Call" is just below the radio buttons.

the admin of the page then, can select any phone number and click call button to initiate a call with the phone number.

I am planning not to use VOIP.

In last two days, I learnt about TWILIO,freeswitch, and JTAPI but not able to find the best soluton.

if someone has worked on any such functionality , kindly be a help

Answer (score 2):

Twilio employee here..

In general, there are really two approaches. One is to make the button kick off something else to actually make the call. You could use Skype or to stick with us, you could use Twilio Client which is Javascript-based and turns your browser into a phone. More info: http://www.twilio.com/api/client

Alternatively, you could make a call flow that - after clicking the button - it automatically dials the user and then dials the person you're trying to call. This will be a little more expensive as there are two outbound dialing legs but if you want to skip the pure VoIP route, this may be a better option. Example: http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call

I'll keep an eye on this thread if you run into any problems.

Comment: Hi Casey,
Thanks for your inputs and Twilio is really a great palatform , but unfortunately I am looking for something open source to dial a number through modem or through EPBAX, would appreciate if you cud help me here.
I see JTAPI, JAVA Comm & Astrix are there for telephony but seems not many people are using this also I have yet to fully understand the implementation of JTAPI, java comm ...so Any help here would be highly appreciated..... thnx in advance :)

Comment: I used to use Asterisk 5+ years ago but haven't touched it recently, so I can't be helpful there. Sorry.

Comment: Casey,
How much it will cost me to use Twilio client and I will be based in Malaysia. Does Twilio support from malaysia ?

Comment: Outbound calls to Malaysia are about $0.04-0.05/minute as detailed here - http://www.twilio.com/pricing/international-calling-rates#searchbar

Answer (score 1):

I have spent much time thinking about the same question with SMS, and it turns out that twillio is the best bet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937120/how-can-i-send-a-massive-number-of-sms-messages-without-incurring-a-huge-bill

You can use android simulator and wire it back to your client via flash, but I can't imagine how bad the latency can be. You can also use the unofficial google voice api. Overall, to achieve google voice's capability without using voip or a vender is ill advised. I can't imagine how you can do this while preserving sound quality and at the same time keeping latency to a minimum. Think about it, if you are the person who is receiving the call, where is the call coming from? it must be from a number! I think what you mean is not that you don't want to use VOIP, but you don't want to pay the price tag.

Comment: Hi Bernardw, thanks for the reply.
I want to call a phone number through modem attached to my J2EE application , so that I dont use any 3rd party.

Comment: i hope you realize that if you do this, you can only sustain one call at any given time, and the hardware you would need is something similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_telephone_adapter so that you computer can interpret the analog signal coming out of your land-line. After that you would probably have to write your own package to convert the digital package back to sound. cheers.